# "Site can't be reached" error during CiviCRM Joomla install

Tags: joomla, installation, install

When I try to "Install from folder" (CiviCRM 4.7.15) on Joomla (3.6.5) I get the error "Site can't be reached." I've tried the troubleshooting tips listed here: https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Installing+CiviCRM+for+Joomla#InstallingCiviCRMforJoomla-5.Trouble-shootingResources

But to no avail! I've also noticed that if I have my FTP client open and connected to my server, it gets disconnected at the exact same time that the install fails (about two minutes into the process). I then usually have com_civicrm folders in my Components and Admini/Components folders and a civicrm folder in my media folder, and one time I had civicrm in my plugins folder and it was working, but because I didn't get a confirmation screen I tried to reinstall properly and now nothing works!

Thanks for any help!
John

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that I needed more privaleges on my MySQL account, ones that my host did not give me the option of enabling. Here is the list of requirements: https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/CiviCRM+MySQL+Permission+Requirements

My host wouldn't let me do Triggers or create routines, so I had to switch hosts and it now works. 
In case anyone is reading this with the same problem, I looked for hosts on CiviCRM.org to find one that was compatible, and they were able to transfer me over and assist with the install for free with a new registration.